# Fill information in textbox before sending email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

After I click send, the textbox that is not filled turns red.

After the popped up message to continue I click yes.

I am unable to continue to fill in the blanks and the email is sent.

```
Private Sub Send_Click()

    'Check the value if blank
    If Branchname.Value = "" Or _
       subject.Value = "" Or _
       Makername.Value = "" Or _
       Checkername.Value = "" Or _
       Filename.Value = "" Then

        'If value=0 then change the highlight to notify user
        If Branchname.Value = "" Then
            Branchname.BackColor = vbRed
        End If
  
        If subject.Value = "" Then
            subject.BackColor = vbRed
        End If
  
        If Makername.Value = "" Then
            Makername.BackColor = vbRed
        End If
  
        If Checkername.Value = "" Then
            Checkername.BackColor = vbRed
        End If
  
        If Filename.Value = "" Then
            Filename.BackColor = vbRed
        End If
  
        'Display msgbox to prompt user
        If MsgBox("Form is not complete.Do you want to continue?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo) <> vbYes Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    'Call emailfunction
    Call Sendbasicemaillatebingding

    'reset everything
    Call Resetform

    'drop the form
    Unload Me     
End Sub
```

Comment: You should click "No" to fill in the blanks. If you click "Yes" it continues the macro and sends the email, while "No" will run into `Exit Sub` and it won't send the email. • *"Do you want to continue?"* In this case means: "Do you want to continue with sending the email even if the form is incomplete?".

Comment: I disagree with the vote to close. Logical errors, even if they are only perceived logical errors, are within the scope defined by the help center: "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development."

Answer (score 1):

Because that's what you are telling it to do. The way your code is set up, if you click "No" in the `MsgBox`, you exit the Send function and go back to the form. If you click "Yes," you continue execution, calling your send email function, calling a reset form function, and then unloading the form.

Now, when you ask the user "Do you want to continue?" you're asking if the user wants to send the email without completing the form. If the user says yes, then you continue sending the email. If no, then you go back to the form, with the incomplete boxes highlighted in red. Again, that's what your code does. If that isn't what you want to do, then you need to work out what you *do* want to do and implement it.

Also, there's no logical reason to reset a form and then unload it. Unloading it removes it from the screen. So, it looks like you have to work out the logic of your program flow. Presumably, you want to reset the form and keep it open. Unload the form from some sort of "Exit" button that's next to your "Send" button.